# While loop continuing when condition met

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while, break

So, I'm writing an engineering type program for my ENGR200 class and I am  thoroughly stuck. I've never taken a programming language before, but I have scoured the web for the last 3 hours testing etc every variation of loops and I can't seem to get anything to work.

What I want the program to do is

1. receive a user input
2. test if it lies within acceptable range
3. if it doesn't I want it to send an error message
4. prompt a new entry
5. if it does meet the acceptable range I want it to continue onto the rest.

My current code is below:

```
    /*******************************************************************************
AUTHOR SECTION

   ENGR 200.xx                                               DATE: mm/dd/yyyy

   PROGRAM: #                               Author:
********************************************************************************
PROGRAM DESCRIPTION 

   This program will allow the user to enter the temperature in fahrenheit
   and relative humidity in percent. Then ask the user wether he/she will be in
   direct sun. Next, if an unacceptable temp or relative humidiy is entered, an
   error message should be printed. If the error check is passed, the program
   will then calculate the heat index and humidex. The program will then print
   these values temp in degrees fahrenheit, the temperature in degree celsius,
   the relative humidity, the heat index, and the humidex. Based on the heat
   index value the program will prin and appropriate warning below the output.
   If heat index is below 80F print "No health concerns expected."


DESCRIPTION OF VARIABLES
NAME            TYPE                DESCRIPTION
heat_index      double              Calculated value for heat index
humi_index      double              Calculated value for humidex
humi_f          double              Calculated variable used in humi_index
temp            int                 User input for degrees fahrenheit
temp_c          double              Calculated value for conversion f --> C
relat_humid     int                 User input of relative humidity in % [0-100]
humi_pow        double              power value for humi_f calculation
direct_sun      char                User input for direct sun contact or not
heat_index_y    double              heat_index + 15
humi_index_y    double              humi_index + 9


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
FORMULAS

humi_pow = (((7.5)*(temp_c))/((237.7)+(temp_c)))


heat_index = 
(-42.379)+(2.04901523*temp)+
(10.14333127*relat_humid)-
(0.22475541*temp*relat_humid)-
((6.83783*(pow(10,-3)))*(pow(temp),2))-
((5.481717*(pow(10,-2)))*(pow(relat_humid,2)))+
((1.22874)*(pow(10,-3))*(pow(temp,2))*(relat_humid))+
((8.5282)*(pow(10,-4))*(temp)*(pow(relat_humid,2)))-
((1.99*(pow(10,-6))*(pow(temp,2))*(pow(relat_humid,2)))

humi_f =
((6.112)*(pow(10,humi_pow)))*((relat_humid)/100.0)

humi_index =
(temp_c+((5.0/9.0)*(humi_f-10)))


*******************************************************************************/

/* Preprocessor directives */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Main function */
int main()
{
   /* Declare variables */
   char direct_sun;
   double heat_index, humi_index, temp_c, humi_pow, humi_f, humi_index_y, 
   heat_index_y, temp, relat_humid;

   /* Print headings */
   printf("********************************************");
   printf("\n         APPARENT HEAT CALCULATION");

   /* Input values */
   printf("\n\nEnter temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ");
   scanf("%d",&temp);
   /* Check valididty of temp */
   while(temp < 67)
   {
    printf("You must input a value greater than 67 degrees fahrenheit.");
    printf("\nEnter temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ");
    scanf("%d",&temp);

    if(temp >= 67)
    {
        break;
    }
   }

   printf("Enter relative humidity (56% as 56)        : ");
   scanf("%d",&relat_humid);
   /* Check validity of relat_humid */
   while(relat_humid <= 0 || relat_humid >= 100)
   {
    printf("You must input a value between 0 and 100.");
    printf("\nEnter relative humidity (56% as 56)        :");
    scanf("%d",&relat_humid);

    if(relat_humid <= 100 && relat_humid >= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
   } 
   printf("Working in direct sun (y/n)?               : ");
   scanf("%c",&direct_sun);

   /* Compute */
   temp_c = ((5.0/9.0)*(temp-32));
   humi_pow = (((7.5)*(temp_c))/((237.7)+(temp_c)));
   humi_f = ((6.112)*(pow(10,humi_pow)))*((relat_humid)/100.0);
   humi_index = (temp_c+((5.0/9.0)*(humi_f-10)));
   heat_index = 
   (-42.379)+(2.04901523*temp)+
   (10.14333127*relat_humid)-
   (0.22475541*temp*relat_humid)-
   ((6.83783*(pow(10,-3)))*(pow(temp,2)))-
   ((5.481717*(pow(10,-2)))*(pow(relat_humid,2)))+
   ((1.22874)*(pow(10,-3))*(pow(temp,2))*(relat_humid))+
   ((8.5282)*(pow(10,-4))*(temp)*(pow(relat_humid,2)))-
   (1.99*(pow(10,-6))*(pow(temp,2))*(pow(relat_humid,2)));
   heat_index_y = heat_index + 15;
   humi_index_y = humi_index + 9;

   /* Print output values */
   printf("\n\nRESULTS");
   printf("\nTemperature (degrees F):");
   printf("\nTemperature (degrees C):");
   printf("\nRelative Humidity:");
   printf("\n\nHeat index:");
   printf("Humidex:");
   printf("WARNING: IF STATEMENT REQUIRED");
   printf("\n********************************************\n\n\n");

   /* Exit the program */
   return 0;
}
/*********************************************************************/
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Where is `temp` defined? What's its type?

Comment: Please explain what behaviour you observe and explain how it differs from what you expected

Comment: Please post what you have so far. Currently, it seems to be incomplete, which makes it difficult for others to look at. Consider posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is updated now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following might do what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUTOFF (67)

int main() {
    int temperature = 0;
    int scanf_result = 0;

    do {
        /* Input values */

        printf("Enter temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ");
        scanf_result = scanf("%d", &temperature);

        fpurge(stdin); // clear out excess or non-numeric input

        /* Check validity of temperature */

        if (scanf_result == 0 || temperature < CUTOFF) {
             fprintf(stderr, "You must input a value greater than %d degrees fahrenheit.\n", CUTOFF);
        }

        } while (temperature < CUTOFF && scanf_result != EOF);

    if (scanf_result == EOF) { // try to handle user typing ^D aka EOT
        fprintf(stderr, "Program terminated by user.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* now do something useful with temperature */

    return 0;
}
```

The test of the return result of `scanf()` protects against really bad input:

```
> ./a.out
Enter temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: dog
You must input a value greater than 67 degrees fahrenheit.
Enter temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: 34
You must input a value greater than 67 degrees fahrenheit.
Enter temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: 103
>
```